# Bootstrap: How to change textbox placeholder to show ErrorMessage?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm validating `bootstrap` `form input` and want to show Error Message instead of default placeholder text.

How can I do it?

This my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtReportYear" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Year" MaxLength="4" ClientIDMode=Static></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

This is jQuery:

```
function ValidateInput() {
   var year = $('#txtReportYear').val();
   var month = $('#txtReportMonth').val();
   var day = $('#txtReportDay').val();

   if (year == '') 
   {
      $('#txtReportYear').placeholder = 'Provide Year';
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Is the any other ways to validate the form?

Comment: you can do that like this: $('#txtReportYear').attr("placeholder","your error message goes here")     since placeholder only shows on empty input box, you need to delete current value like this: $('#txtReportYear').val("")

Comment: Thank's, it worked!! How can I also set a color of that Error Message? I tried to use `$('#txtReportYear').css({'color' : 'red'})` but it did not work

Comment: Just updated my answer to address placeholder color change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/bExWMe).

```
$("#txtReportYear").val("").attr("placeholder","An error occured!");
```

So you need to clear out current value in your `input` box using `.val("")`. Then you can change placeholder using `.attr("placeholder","An error occured!")` to the new message. If you have your error message in a variable, let's say `err_msg`, then you would do this:

```
$("#txtReportYear").val("").attr("placeholder",err_msg);
```

To change the color of placeholder, you can create a new CSS class and add it to the `input` box :

**CSS**

```
.changePlaceColor1::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color:    red;
}

.changePlaceColor2:-moz-placeholder {
   color:    red;
}
.changePlaceColor3::-moz-placeholder {
   color:    red;
}
.changePlaceColor4:-ms-input-placeholder {
   color:    red;
}
```

Then, your click event will change like this:

```
$("#txtReportYear").val("").attr("placeholder","An error occured!").addClass("changePlaceColor1").addClass("changePlaceColor2").addClass("changePlaceColor3").addClass("changePlaceColor4");
```

NOTE: You can add vendor-specific placeholder color class to get it to work cross-browser.

Comment: I updated the answer. I already said as a note that you need to simply add vendor-specific style to make it to work cross-browser. Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the placeholder, I would use the ASP.NET [validators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc295349.aspx) that are built in.

If the year is a required field use:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" Text="Year is required" ControlToValidate="txtReportYear" DisplayMode="Dynamic" />
```